# How can I use GNOME OSTree with Ubuntu Server minimal

Tags: apt, gnome, root

I would like to create a custom Ubuntu based OS using GNOME's OSTree.But I need `apt-get` and other Ubuntu commands .I am OK with not modifying the root directory by using a chroot to install packages .How can I install OSTree on to Ubuntu Server Minimal